# Data truncated from aws lambda to api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a AWS Lambda function that it's triggered by an API Gateway endpoint

1.- The API Gateway endpoint is consumed trough Postman and pass a parameter

2.- The lambda function receive the parameter, prepare a Json String with data (About 500 records)

3.- The lambda function response this to the API Gateway, something like

```
var res = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
    {
        StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Body = r
    };
return res;
```

The problem is that POSTMAN or the API Gateway only show the first 14 records, I test my Lambda function and returns 500 or more. There is a limitation?

Comment: Both AWS Lambda and API Gateway have documented payload limits, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jarmod reading the documentation of lambda, the main point is:

**Invocation payload (request and response)**

6 MB each for request and response (synchronous)

20 MB for each streamed response (synchronous)

256 KB (asynchronous)

In my case my Function was Async at first, after transformed to sync works great!